# How do I tell Gizela Wulflac that Camden is dead?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

I found the death notice for Camden Wulflac, how do I tell Gizela that he's dead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the notice first. After doing some quest I came back to Gorhart and she offered me the quest of finding out what happened to her husband.

Quite straightforward, do a persuasion check and all ends well.

> When talking to Camden, I used a persuasion check to get him to go home to his wife.

Comment: With the persuasion check, do you mean that you told her he was dead, and she accepted that as the final answer?

Comment: @Tristan see updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

I gave her the notice as well, got the follow on quest, and later made things all well during their reunion.

Comment: We used to have a spoiler tag, it got wiped out because it just didn't work well. See [this meta thread](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3300/spoiler-alert-spoiler-dies) for the details.

Comment: @Mana thanks for the info! Wasn't sure how to post about a result that differed from the one the OP found

Answer (score 1):

If you can't find the Death Notice (or sold it for 0 gold, in my case), you can skip it and continue on to the town of Delthin (North East of Gorhart)

> where you can find Camden Wulflac himself, very much alive.
>  
>  You can either convince him to return to his wife, or return to his
>  wife and tell him she's dead.

After which, you can return to Gizela and complete the quest.